# Django django.test.client jquery ready

Tags: jquery, django, testing

I have a template including a js script with a:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  doSomething();
});
```

This works perfectly well when displaying the page with chrome, firefox, IE, whatever. But when I try to unit test my view by using django.test.client this way:

```
from django.test.client import Client

c = Client()
response = c.get(url)
```

The ready function is not called. I'm able to POST and GET through Ajax just find with the test.client, it just that the ready function is not executed when I GET the page itself.
Is there a way to configure the client to actually execute js scripts inside the loaded page ?

Luke

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Django test client tests the responses generated by the Django server. It doesn't test the JavaScript, as that is run on the client, not the server.

You can use [Selenium](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/#liveservertestcase) to test the behaviour of the browser. Django has a `LiveServerTestCase`, which allows you to use the Selenium client. See the docs on [`LiveServerTestCase`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/#liveservertestcase) for more information.

Comment: Ok, should have RTFM. Django docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/testing/) :

>Note that the test client is not intended to be a replacement for Selenium or other “in-browser” frameworks. Django’s test client has a different focus.